# Symfony Mailer AWS Load Balancer

Tags: php, symfony, mailer

I have a php application that uses Symfony Mailer 5.4.0 to send emails to customers and suppliers with attachments like invoices and purchase orders.  The emails are sent and received successfully.  After the send mail task has completed the system should return to the previous screen and display an informational message notifying the user that the email has sent.  This works perfectly in a test environment on servers that are accessed directly by their ip addresses.  The problem I am having is with an instance that is running in an Amazon VPC behind a load balancer.  On that server the emails send successfully however the user is then presented with a blank screen and has to log back into the system to continue working. It appears to time out before displaying the screen, but I do not receive an http notification or error.  I am finding lots of posts on how to set up the Symfony Framework to run behind a load balancer, mostly about configuring it to trust proxies but we are not using the framework, only the Mailer.  I have a ticket open with AWS on this.  Any help / advice will be greatly appreciated.

I have a configuration file that contains logon information for the O365 email accounts we are using.  Everything I am finding in various forums include code to set the framework to trust proxies but none of the folders that are referred to exist in the Mailer configuration.

Comment: "however the user is then presented with a blank screen" - a blank screen often means a PHP error, have you checked the logs? If emails are sending successfully on PROD, my gut would tell me that Mailer is working correctly and no amount of configuration would affect your problem, and you might need to look elsewhere for the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea from the start to wait when mailer will end its work. IMO, better solution will be to dispatch a message (using messenger component) and asynchronously send the email w/o any impact on user's experience